# Summation $\sum_{x\in [0, 1]} f(x)$ over all real numbers $x \in [0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

I am wondering if the concept of a summation over all $x \in [0, 1]$ would be useful. It would generalize the traditional concept of series. For instance:

$\sum_{x \in [0, 1] \cap \{1, 1/2, 1/3, \cdots\}} x^2 = \pi^2/6.$

The definition I have in mind is as follows. Define level-0 numbers as $L_0 =\{0\}$, level-1 numbers as $L_1 =\{1/2\}$, level-2 numbers as $L_2 =\{1/4, 3/4\}$, level-3 numbers as $L_3=\{1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8\}$, level-4 numbers as $L_4=\{1/16, 3/16, 5/16, 7/16, 9/16, 11/16, 13/16, 15/16\}$ and so on. Then

$\sum_{x\in [0, 1]} f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{x \in L_k} f(x).$

You can define absolute convergence easily. Let's denote $y_k = \sum_{x \in L_k} f(x)$. Then the series converges absolutely if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty y_k$ converges absolutely.

A possible applications is to define a summation over all rational numbers in $[0, 1]$. Is my concept new or old, interesting or not, or does not make any real sense?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  You appear to only be summing over rational numbers with denominators of the form $2^k$.  Was that your intent?

Comment: And, in any ordinary sense, the sum of all the rationals between $0$ and $1$ would diverge (as, for instance) the sum would contain infinitely many terms $>\frac 12$).

Comment: @Lulu: correct. Only at the limit ($L_\infty$) would all numbers be included. Most sums would diverge, but some would converge. For instance if $f(x)$ is a function of the number of digits of $x$ in base $2$ that are non-zero, depending on the function $f$.

Comment: No...$\frac 13$ would never appear in your sum.

Comment: More broadly:  if all your summands are non-negative, then you can rearrange the terms without changing the sum, so this summation would be the same as any other.  If the terms have mixed signs then you've chosen one particular order, but the choice of the ordering may alter the sum.

Comment: Note:  The header to your problem refers to "all real numbers".  That is a very different thing that anything your post actually mentions.

Comment: What about $\int_0^1 f(x) \; dx$? That's analogous to a sum over the interval.

Comment: @Lulu: You would need to visualize the $L_k$ structure as an infinite binary tree, with any number in $[0,1]$ represented by an infinite path in that tree. So $1/3$ can't be represented by a finite path in that tree, sure, but by an infinite path, right? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I'll change the title, it is confusing.

Comment: I don't understand...you've defined $L_k=\{\frac 1{2^k}, \cdots, \frac {2^k-1}{2^k}\}$.  There is no "path".

Comment: Let me think more about this.

Comment: @VincentGranville $\frac13\neq \frac p{2^n}$, hence $\frac13\not\in L_k$ for any $k$. It is true that closure of union of $Lk$'s $\textrm{cl}\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}L_k$ is equal to the whole interval $[0,1]$, but you don't take any closures here.

Comment: Vincent. may be you are missing the fact that even though every initial segment of that infinite path is, in a sense, covered in the sum, the whole path (or rather, the number it corresponds to) is NOT. In other words, the sum contains contributions only from those values of $x\in[0,1]$ that, when written in base two, terminate at some finite point.

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin Well, the integral isn't the sum of the values of $f(x)$ but the limit of sum of the areas of rectangles of height $f(x)$ and base approaching infinitismal.  Example: $\int_0^1 x dx=\frac 12 < 1$ but $\sum_{x\in[0,1]} x \le \sum_{x=\frac 1n|n\in \mathbb N} x =\infty$.  ... I'm not sure there is any use to this question. But I haven't given it enough thought for such a blanket condemnation. The OP seems to be only doing countable sums and I'm not sure how to even define uncountable sums and unless $f(x)\ne 0$ only countably many times the sum will be infinite.

Comment: Not unlike that $0.333\ldots$ is not an element of the set $S=\{0.3,0.33,0.333,0.3333,\ldots\}$. The reason is that all the numbers in the set $S$ have only finitely many (non-zero) decimals, but $0.333\ldots$ has infinitely many.

Comment: See my comment below Maja Blumenstein's answer. I think it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some exposition on the framework of uncountable sums. Maybe this will scratch your itch.

Let $A$ be a set with some unknown cardinality, and let $x_\alpha$ be elements of a topological vector space (for simplicity assume $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A} \subset \mathbb{R}$.) Our aim is define the unordered sum:

$$
\sum_{\alpha \in A} x_\alpha
$$
First, let us nail down some set-theoretic terminology. A binary relation $\prec$ on a set $\mathcal{F}$ is  called a a partial order on $\mathcal{F}$ if for evert $I,J,K \in \mathcal{F}$, we have that:

- $I \prec I$ (reflexivity)
- $I\prec J, \ J \prec K \implies I \prec K$ (Transitivity)
- $I \prec J , \ J \prec I \implies I = J$ (Antisymmetry)

We call this a partial order because not all elements of $\mathcal{F}$ may be comparable with this relation. For the subset $A$ in question, let us consider :$$
\mathcal{F} = \{B \subset A : B \text{ is finite}\} 
$$
I.e., all finite subsets of $B$. You can check that this is a partially order set with $\prec = \subset$, i.e.  $A\prec B \iff A \subset B$. Note that if $I,J \in \mathcal{F}$, we have some $K$ such that $ I \subset K$, $J\subset K$, and hence $I \prec K$ , $J\prec K$ (consider $K = I \cup J$). Any ordered set where any two elements have an element "greater than them", is known as a directed set. $\mathcal{F}$ is a directed set.

Given a finite subset $I \subset A$, we can define a partial sum:
$$
S_I = \sum_{\alpha \in I} x_\alpha
$$
Thus, we may say that $\sum_{\alpha \in A}x_\alpha$ converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if for all $\epsilon >0$ , we have $I\subset A$ with $I$ finite, such that:$$
\left |x - \sum_{\alpha \in I} x_\alpha \right| < \epsilon
$$
We have the following result: If $\sum_{\alpha \in A} x_\alpha$ converges, then $x_\alpha \neq 0 $ for at most countably many $\alpha$. The main idea of the proof is to consider sets $I_n \in \mathcal{F}$ with:

$$
\left |\sum_{\alpha \in I_n} x_\alpha \right| < \frac{1}{n}
$$
The sets $I_n$ are finite, so their union is countable, and thus so is the set of elements with terms larger than $0$.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, $$\sum_{x\in [0, 1]} f(x) \neq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{x \in L_k} f(x)$$ because $$\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty L_k\neq[0,1].$$
Secondly, for any uncountable set $S$ sum $\sum_{x\in S} x$ diverges because the series contains infinitely many terms strictly greater than $\varepsilon\neq0$.

Summation over all rationals from $[0,1]$ (or even all rationals) is nothing new, it's just rephrasing theory of the ordinary series, as all $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q\cap[0,1]}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are countable. 
Say you have a set of real numbers indexed by rationals $\{x_r|r\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, there is a sequence of all rationals, say $q_1,q_2,q_3,...$.
Then, instead of the sum $$\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}x_r$$ we can work with sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{q_n}$$
which is "the usual" series over naturals.
(Here I talk only about absolute convergence, so we can rearrange the terms, I can't think of a reasonable definition of conditional convergence of sums over rationals.)

Comment: I see your point. It needs to be defined differently: $\sum_{x \in [0, 1]} f(x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{y\in L_k} f(y)$. This assumes $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

One way of defining such a thing is to define a measure $\tau$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ by $$\tau(A)=\begin{cases} |A| & \text{if A has finitely many elements} \\  \infty & otherwise\end{cases}$$

and then define $\sum_{x\in I} f(x) := \int_I f d\tau$. Now a relevant question to ask would be: "What functions are in $\mathcal{L^1}(\tau)=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \: | \: \int|f|d\tau < \infty\}$??".

If there exist an interval I such that $f(x)>\varepsilon$ for all $x\in I$, then $\sum_{x\in I} f(x) \geq \int_I \varepsilon d\tau = \varepsilon \tau(I) = \infty$, hence any continous function, which is not 0 everywhere is not in $\mathcal{L^1}(\tau)$.

Now suppose that $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\tau)$ and set $K=\int_I |f| d\tau$, then the set $\{x \: | \: |f(x)| \geq K/n \}$ has atmost $n$ elements, and is therefore finite, this means that

$$ X = \{x \: | \: |f(x)|> 0\} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{x \: | \: |f(x)| \geq K/n \}$$
is a countable set, which means that $X$ can be written as a sequence $\{x_n \: | \: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $f$ can be written as $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n) \cdot \chi_{x_n}$ and by the dominated convergence theorem
$$ \sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}fd\tau = \int_\mathbb{R}\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)  \cdot \chi_{x_n} d\tau = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{x_n}f(x_n)d\tau = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)\tau(\{x_n\}) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n) $$